# How to auto focus the descendants of a FocusScope when the canRequestFocus changes in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a situation where I have two set of `widgets`. Both sets are children of a `stack`. And I am conditionally showing the second set of widgets in a `stateful widget` (popup). And my requirement is that when the popup is showing, its descendants focusable and not the background widget's and when it is not showing, the background gets back the focus.

The below code almost works. I use a `FocusScope` widget to restrict the focus. But the issue is that **when the popup is not showing, the background `TextField` is not regaining the focus.** (I have to manually press the `TextField` or press TAB to get back the focus).

Please take a look at the code.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: const Material(child: MyHomePage()),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _show = false;
  final _normalFN = FocusNode();
  final _popupFN = FocusNode();

  void _onPressNormal() {
    setState(() {
      _show = true;
      _popupFN.requestFocus();
    });
  }

  void _onPressPopup() {
    setState(() {
      _show = false;
      _normalFN.requestFocus();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _normalFN.dispose();
    _popupFN.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          FocusScope(
              canRequestFocus: !_show,
              child: Column(children: [
                TextField(focusNode: _normalFN, autofocus: true),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: _onPressNormal, child: const Text("open popUp")),
              ])),
          if (_show) Popup(_onPressPopup, _popupFN),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Popup extends StatelessWidget {
  const Popup(this.onPress, this.focusNode, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final void Function() onPress;
  final FocusNode focusNode;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      width: 300,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          TextField(focusNode: focusNode),
          const SizedBox(height: 30),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: onPress, child: const Text('close'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a hard question to answer? You flutter folks should be able I think... Is there any confusion in my question?

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the state (hiding your popup) and focus in the same frame/build loop, that usually doesn't work. You can use a post frame callback or any other form of delayed execution.

```dart
  void _onPressPopup() {
    setState(() {
      _show = false;
    });
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _normalFN.requestFocus());
  }
```

Comment: `scheduleMicrotask` works nicely here